# write to many text file without overwrite with c#

Tags: c#, string

hi all I tried to write string to  many txt file make some replacement and write to new file that's my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++){
  if (str[i]==str2[i]){
    str=str.replace(str[i],str3[i])
    File.WriteAllText("text.txt", str);
  }
}
```

ignore the name of file because i made it dynamically but the problem is 
when the condition is true 5 times the files will be written equal 5 but i found just one file contain all replacement at all  !!

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please visit [mcve] and try to [edit] your post to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write multiple lines to the one file, try to use StreamWriter class. Then use Write or WriteLine methods, to wite some text to your file